# Force redirect after form is submitted through a server side include

Tags: php, forms, redirect, form-submit

I'm trying to make the PHP contact form which is in a server side include on another page redirect to the thank you page when submitted.

The form is in the page page as an include like this:

```
<div id="formArea">
<?php include 'form.php'; ?>
</div>
```

and currently have the redirect set as this:

```
header("Location: thankyou.php");
```

The form works fine and the messages are going to my inbox. Also would like to note that when the form.php page is opened as it is without being an include it does actually redirect to thankyou.php

Any idea how I can achieve this task?

Thanks

Comment: Where is your header in the code? If it's on the same page as the html, you'll get an error as you're sending information to the browser - which has its own headers - before you send your header, thereby making it not redirect.

Comment: The header is in the form.php file

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to set a HTTP header *after* the headers have been sent (because you've already started outputting HTML), therefore the redirect header *Location* is never sent with the request to the server.

### Server-side solution

You must call the `header()` function *before* any output.

### Client-side solution

If you still insist on doing a redirect in **form.php** you can do a JavaScript (client-side) redirect:

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "someurl.php";</script>
```

### Debugging

I also suggest you enabling warnings and errors while developing your application (remember to disable in production though!) because your code should have produced a *headers_sent* warning. .

```
ini_set( 'display_errors', 'on' );
error_reporting( E_ALL );
```

Comment: Ahh thanks, here's the error I got if that makes any sense? Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /homepages/44/d124134658/htdocs/Fujitsu/17469_FUJ_Retail/landing_pages/lm_no_banner/index.php:7) in /homepages/44/d124134658/htdocs/Fujitsu/17469_FUJ_Retail/landing_pages/lm_no_banner/form.php on line 72

Comment: It's just explaining to you that headers were already sent to the browser, so it can't send your header to redirect. Even if you don't explicitly tell it to, the server still sends headers on HTML and other text that it sends out to tell the browser how to read it, what to do with it, what it is, etc, and since your header came after the HTML, it resulted in double headers, which the browser, and server, dislike. So yeah, the error supports this answer.